# What are the implications of Prime Number Theorem in Cryptography?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, cryptography

I know that primes and prime factorization are the basis concepts in cryptography. However, I would like to know how does the Prime Number Theorem come into picture in cryptography, since it states that the prime counting function is asymptotically equal to $\frac{n}{\ln n}$. In other words, what is the implication of knowing number of primes less than $n$, in cryptography?

Answer (score 1):

It has indirect implications on how easy it is to find the large primes needed in RSA.

Comment: See for instance http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11106/prime-number-theorem-rsa.